# How to write where clause that has parenthesis using MS SQL Server Report Builder 3.0

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I am using "Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0" on "SQL Server Reporting Services 2012". As I am passing some parameters from main report to drillthrough report I have to use Graphical Query Designer to generate SQL query.

In WHERE clause of SQL there are conditions like:

```
`.... WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND (condition3 OR condition4 OR condition5 OR condition6)`
```

I know how to add AND/OR conditions by using appropriate "Operator" from Graphical Query Designer but I can't find a way to add parenthesis after AND.

How can I do this using Report Builder 3.0? I don't have "Business Intelligence Development Studio".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in the query designer, click on Edit As Text in the top left. You can type queries in the text based query designer window that opens. Got his answer from another forum so just wanted to post here in case anyone finds this post for same question in future.